# Trying to split each input line into groups and store in hashmap

Tags: java

```
static HashMap<Integer, String> names = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    while (in.hasNext())
        s = in.nextLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < s.split(" ").length; j++) {
            names.put(i, s.split(" ")[j]);
        }
        i++;
}
```

I'm trying to read each line of input in and split it based on spaces and then assign each element separately to the same hash key.

Ex input

> john joe bob
>
> james
>
> henry george

Should go into a hashmap like so

> 1: john
>
> 1: joe
>
> 1: bob
>
> 2: james
>
> 3: henry
>
> 3: george

Also what's the best way to get out of the loop when i'm done entering input?

Comment: A key can only point to 1 value. Also, what is the question / what's not working?

Comment: What i'm trying to do with it is get each element of a line in the same "group" if that makes any sense. I thought a hashmap was a good way to do this maybe not though.

Comment: Since I don't know what "group" is it doesn't make sense to me. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just some way to identify that members are from the same group

Comment: Then do what [assylias suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34697869/1803551).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map is a key/value collection where each key is linked to exactly one value. In your case you seem to want several values per key - one option would be something like below, where each key (line number) maps to a list of names:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> names = ...;
```

To populate the map you will need to create a list for each line, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String s = in.nextLine();
        names.put(i, Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
        i++;
    }
}
```

ps: I assumed that the missing brackets at the end of the `while` line was a typo.

Comment: You might want to also answer "*what's the best way to get out of the loop when i'm done entering input?*"

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind what's the best way to print out the data?

Comment: @BenArnao you can print the map directly or if you want a different formatting you can loop over the map's entryset and print the content the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would just use a list inside your map.
like this:

`static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> names = new HashMap<>();`

Full working code example:

```
int i = 0;
while (in.hasNext()) {
    String s = in.nextLine();
    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("break")) break;
    ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
    names.put(i, namesList);
    for (int j = 0; j < s.split(" ").length; j++) {
        namesList.add(s.split(" ")[j]);
    }
    i++;
}

System.out.println();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<String>> entry : names.entrySet()) {
    System.out.print(entry.getKey()+": ");
    for (String s : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.print(s + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```